# WARNING: Unable to find module repositories

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

I tried to install Docker on activated windows server 2016 standard.
I executed `“Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force”` but failed. It suggested that can not find PSGallery. I executed `"Get-PSRepository"`.

The error:

> **WARNING: *Unable to find module repositories*.**

I googled 3 ways to solve it but none of them worked.

1. I executed `Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201     -Verbose -Force` successfully.
2. I installed chocolatey successfully.
3. I execute `"powershell Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted"` but failed. It asked me to use `"Register-PSRepository -Default"`.

I tried `"powershell Register-PSRepository -Default -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted"` but still failed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Same issue: https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/183

Answer (score 83):

With [the deprecation of TLS 1.0 and 1.1 for PowerShell Gallery as of April 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-tls-support/), the cmdlets Update-Module and Install-Module became broken. Thus, [according to this article](https://dev.to/darksmile92/powershell-disabled-support-for-tls-1-0-for-the-gallery-update-module-and-install-module-broken-1oii), some commands need to be executed to bring them alive again:

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 
Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.4 -SkipPublisherCheck
```

If that still doesn't work, then run the following commands:

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Register-PSRepository -Default -Verbose
Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were also recently deprecated at NuGet.org:
[image: nuget.org deprecated TLS 1.0 and 1.1]
But [that was also previously announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/).

Comment: No repository with the name 'PSGallery' was found

Answer (score 37):

Simply running `Register-PSRepository -Default` (without any additional parameters) worked for me. After that, the Gallery was successfully registered:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
```

Answer (score 23):

### My problem was the missing Proxy config

best solution from comments:
https://www.zerrouki.com/working-behind-a-proxy/
thanks to [@Vadzim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603516/vadzim)

---

In PowerShell open Profile

```
PS> notepad $PROFILE
```

this opens Notepad with your profile setting, will be created of not exists.
then add:

```
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy = new-object system.net.webproxy('http://webproxy.yourCompany.com:PORT')
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = $true
```

somehow my local proxy is set but doesn't work.
same problem later with Docker, =>

```
> PS> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

then restart docker service

Comment: Take a look also at https://www.zerrouki.com/working-behind-a-proxy/ and https://spaghettidba.com/2017/12/19/recovering-the-psgallery-repository-behind-a-corporate-proxy/

Comment: It would be beneficial to your answer to quote the better parts then. )

Comment: I've seen this answer mentioned a lot but I'm having the error on my home PC with no proxy...

Comment: For PowerShell Core v7, this is what works:
`[System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::DefaultProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8888', $true, @(";*.bypassdomain.com"))`

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 7):

I got a similar message. I ran `Register-PSRepository -default` and it registered ok. Then I ran `Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`. I didn't combine the commands, but it worked.

I spent over an hour trying to pass credentials to the proxy the same way I do for Exchange Online, but no love. I disconnected and used our guest WiFi instead.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing which hasn't been mentioned.
You would indeed need to run

```
notepad $profile
```

and copy paste this bit changing your proxy details:

```
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy = new-object system.net.webproxy('http://webproxy.yourCompany.com:PORT')
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.credentials =  System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = $true
```

But if you have HTTPS Inspection turned on, you might want to add the Man-in-the-middle Certificate to the `"Trusted Root Certification Authorities"`

Answer (score 1):

Configuring correct Tls version resulted in the following errors:

```
PS /> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12                                  
PS /> Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.4 -SkipPublisherCheck
Install-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'PowerShellGet'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all
available registered module repositories.
PS /> Get-PSRepository -Verbose
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
```

If you are working behind a corporate proxy service you might need to add trust to the CA.

```bash
cp my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
update-ca-certificates
```

After updating our trust store we are able to query the powershell repository.

```
PS /> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```