# Can not install module Power BI in powershell

Tags: powershell, module, powerbi

I need to install module Power BI in Powershell.

I did next steps as admin:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt'. Try Get-PSRepository to see a

ll available registered module repositories.

At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21

+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters

+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

 


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PSRepository

WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Register-PSRepository -Default


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PSRepository

WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
```

I have tried force intallation.
I searched forums and nothing helps!

Comment: Did you already try solutions from [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43323123/503046)? If you find one that works, please post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Did you get a solution? We have a CI process installing a module that has suddenly stopped finding the module and if I run the command on my machine I get the same issue. I tried forcing TLS version